# Links are not clickable in Rails 3 and HAML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have a Rails 3.1 app with HAML and I'm trying to set up the homepage with links to other sites. My Haml code looks like this:

```
.home-container
  %section.news
    %a{:href => "http://www.google.com"} Google
```

The page is the home page that gets yielded to the application and there's a sidebar partial that gets rendered after it that has a Twitter feed. I have tried a ton of syntaxs for links including regular html and all I get is the text, the link is not actually clickable so nothing happens when I click it. I have tested it in both Firefox and Chrome and I can see in the inspector that it's an actual link although I can inspect the element directly, I have to open up the body, divs, etc. Google search is coming up completely fruitless.

I have no idea what's going on and what other possible information would be relevant. Let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: Can you paste the generated HTML?

Comment: is ther any live link? so that we can resolve it ..please

Comment: <div class='home-container'>
<section class='news'>
<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>
</section>
</div>

Comment: It's a private site so I can't show a live link. But above the is the view source output for that section.

Comment: The syntax you’re using is correct. Do you have any css or javascript on the page?

Comment: Yes there's some CSS for the layout and pictures everything. Also javascript using jquery.tweetable.js for a twitter feed.

Comment: Is there some javascript making the link unclickable perhaps?

Comment: When I remove the javascript, it still doesn't work. Would CSS do something?

Comment: @Anoel It’s possible for css to prevent clicking (if unlikely). Try removing all javascript and css and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah it was the z-indexes with the css (see below answer). Thanks for trying to help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with some help from a friend, the problem was the CSS. Specifically the content of the home-container was given a z-index of -1 with the header and picture getting a z-index of 1 and 2 without any relative positioning. So the content was getting put behind the header content so I couldn't click on any of the links. After removing the z-index of -1 from the content, it now works and I can click the link. To add the z-index back, I made the content 1 and the header 2 and added, position: relative; to the css of both.

Answer (score 0):

```
try

.home-container
  %section.news
    %= link_to 'Google', "http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: Its giving me: Invalid tag: "%=raw (link_to 'Google', "google.com")".

Comment: %= raw (link_to 'Google', "google.com"), note I kept a space between = and raw

Comment: when I removed the % to get it to work, it still gives me an unclickable link